# Excel file send through Send grid attachment C# is corrupted

Tags: sendgrid, email-attachments

I'm using sendgrid to send mails with attachments. But seems like excel file is corrupted in the mail. This is the code I'm using

```
byte[] byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(@"fullpath\test.xlsx"));

msg.Attachments = new List<SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment>
{
    new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment
    {
        Content = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData),
        Filename = "test.xlsx",
        Type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        Disposition = "attachment"
    }
};
```

On opening of excel file, I'm getting a popup "We found a problem with content...If you trust click "Yes". On Yes, Excel cannot open this file. Can anyone please help me on this
#Sendgrid

Comment: Can you try 

var messageEmail = new SendGridMessage();
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
messageEmail.AddAttachment("Name.xls", file);

Comment: Thanks Zahid. Your comment helped me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I think the issue may be that you are getting the byte data by reading the file as text and then converting that text to bytes through the lens of ASCII encoding. It may work better to just [read the file as bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-6.0) initially.

Try:

```cs
byte[] byteData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"fullpath\test.xlsx");

msg.Attachments = new List<SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment>
{
    new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment
    {
        Content = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData),
        Filename = "test.xlsx",
        Type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        Disposition = "attachment"
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes you were right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
msg.AddAttachment("test.xlsx"); // Physical file path
```

Make assure file path is relevant

or You try with Bytes as well,

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); 
var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
msg.AddAttachment("Name.xls", file);
```

Comment: The code you mentioned in comment was working                                                                 
             var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); 
            msg.AddAttachment("ConsumptionDataSample.xlsx", file);